# My 3D printer is only printing 2 hours of a print

Tags: print-quality, anycubic-mega-zero

My 3D printer is only printing 2 hours of a print before it stops extruding filament. I have an Anycubic Mega Zero 2.0, it printed the print I was printing before but just recently it started happening.

I tried getting new nozzles. At first it seemed to work but I tried printing 3 of the skeleton fish and it just printed for 2 hours.

I don't have an Ender branded 3D printer that's just my build surface.

[image: The picture of the fish. I don't have an Ender, that's just the build surface]

Comment: I dont think that is the model btw

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! There are obvious reasons when filament stops extruding, but, a more sharp close-up of the print is required.

Comment: Ill have to get my phone then, i took it with my laptop

Comment: Is it a direct drive or Bowden tube?

Comment: Its through a tube

Comment: is it exactly 2 hours, or more specific, is it the exact same time of printing each time it stops? that points to software. If it's different but "about 2 hours", that sounds more like something overheating to me; run a box/stand /room fan over the printer while printing to see if that helps.